# How to integrate a wordpress blog into an existing react website ? (as a www.xxxx.com/blog)

Tags: wordpress, reactjs

I would like a blog (that have been created, fully with wordpress) to be accessible via my already existing react website (www.xxxx.com) as (www.xxx.com/blog). Is that possible ? I have been searching over the internet to find a solution but could not find any with react/js... 
Thank you !

Comment: i think this have nothing to do with react/js .. wordpress uses PHP + SQL database, so if your server allow this, you have to simple install it in this folder

Comment: in the root of your existing site just create a directory and named it as blog and then put wordpress inside that folder this will work

Comment: It also depends on how you serve your React website. If it's an Apache/nginx configuration where you just serve static files (index.html, bundle.js, etc.) from a DocumentRoot, then you can easily serve WP content from a subdirectory as described in answers here. If your setup is a little more complex, like for instance a node server serving your React app that includes a catch-all route (to delegate routing to React-Router on the client, for example), then you'll have to create an exception for your WP subdirectory using middleware in your node server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WordPress is PHP and MySQL, not Javascript (React). But check if your host allows PHP/MySQL allongisde React.

The WordPress Codex has all the info you need on [Integrating WordPress with Your Website (WordPress Codex)](https://codex.wordpress.org/Integrating_WordPress_with_Your_Website). You will need PHP and MySQL. See [Hosting Requirements (WordPress Codex)](https://wordpress.org/about/requirements/).

> First, assume you have an existing site at http://myexample.com. Next,
>   create a new sub-directory (folder) at your site and call it 'blog'
>   (you could use something other than blog, but you must create this
>   sub-directory). So you now have an empty sub-directory at
>   http://myexample.com/blog/. Now, download WordPress and upload all of
>   its files into this new folder, and install WordPress.

Then, use the header on your `index.php` file in `/blog/` :

```
<?php
require('/the/path/to/your/wp-blog-header.php');
get_header(); 
?>
```

Read [Integrating WordPress with Your Website (WordPress Codex)](https://codex.wordpress.org/Integrating_WordPress_with_Your_Website)

Answer (score 0):

Easiest but not the best way would be to use [iframe](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe) tag. For doing this you specify local page with your blog as ***src***.